# What is the best buffer size when using BinaryReader to read big files (>1 GB)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, performance, filesystems

I'm reading binary files and here is a sample:

```
public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        ......
    }

}
```

Obviously the buffer size (16*1024) has a great role in performance. I've read that it depends on the I/O technology ([SATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA), [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive), [SCSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI), etc.) and also the fragment size of the partition which file exists on it (we can define during the formatting the partition).

But here is the question:
**Is there any formula or best practice to define the buffer size?** Right now, I'm defining based on trial-and-error.

**Edit:**
I've tested the application on my server with different buffer sizes, and I get the best performance with 4095*256*16 (16 MB)!!! 4096 is 4 seconds slower.

Here are some older posts which are very helpful but I can't still get the reason:

- *[Faster (unsafe) BinaryReader in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238388/faster-unsafe-binaryreader-in-net)*
- *[Optimum file buffer read size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552107/optimum-file-buffer-read-size)*
- *[File I/O with streams - best memory buffer size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033771/file-io-with-streams-best-memory-buffer-size)*
- *[How do you determine the ideal buffer size when using FileInputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream)*

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64538/tr-2004-136.doc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining buffer size when working with files in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207407/determining-buffer-size-when-working-with-files-in-c)

Comment: Title of your post does not match sample code... Also I'm not sure why would you read in blocks if you return single byte array ([Stream.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.length.aspx) works fine for file streams)...

Comment: @Alexei it is hard to predict that OP is really doing, it is possible that returned array is not the read array.

Comment: @ST3 I really hope `ReadFully` means read stream and return full content... but you are absolutely right, there is no way to predict what method is actually doing/if it reflects actual problem...

Comment: Side note: please consider showing some proof that "*Obviously* the buffer size has a great role in performance". With as many layers of caches that involved during regular file IO "obviously" is not so obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"[Sequential File Programming Patterns and Performance with .NET](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.PF/0502012)" is a great article in I/O performance improvement.

In page 8 of [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0502012v1) PDF file, it shows that the bandwidth for buffer size bigger than eight bytes, is constant. Consider that the article has been written in 2004 and the hard disk drive is "*Maxtor 250 GB 7200 RPM SATA disk*" and the result should be different by latest I/O technologies.

If you are looking for the best performance take a look at [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.ReadFile) or the page 9 of the PDF file, the un-buffered file performance measurements shows better results:

> In un-buffered I/O, the disk data moves directly between the
>   application’s address space and the device without any intermediate
>   copying.

### Summary

- For single disks, use the defaults of the .NET framework – they deliver excellent performance for sequential file access.
- Pre-allocate large sequential files (using the SetLength() method) when the file is created. This typically improves speed by about 13% when compared to a fragmented file.
- At least for now, disk arrays require un-buffered I/O to achieve the highest performance - buffered I/O can be eight times slower than un-buffered I/O. We expect this problem will be addressed in later releases of the .NET framework.
- If you do your own buffering, use large request sizes (64 KB is a good place to start). Using the .NET framework, a single processor can read and write a disk array at over 800 Mbytes/s using un-buffered I/O.

Answer (score 4):

There is no *best* or *worst* buffer size, but you have to look at the some aspects.

As you are using C#, so you run on Windows, Windows uses [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) and its page size is 4 MB, so it is advisable to use multiples of 4096. So your buffer size is `16*1024 = 4*4096`, and it is a good choice, but to say if it is better or worse than `16*4096` we cannot say.

Everything depends on the situation and the requirements for program. Remember here you cannot choose the best option, but only some better. I recommend to use `4096`, but also you could use your own `4*4096` or even `16*4096`, but remember, that this buffer will be allocated on the heap, so its allocation takes some time, so you don't want to allocate a big buffer, for example `128*4096`.

Comment: +1. Going above 80K will force buffer to go on LOH and it brings its own issues (primary for 32bit processes)... 4-64K is likely the range to stick too for most cases.

Comment: @Alexei, see release notes about Runtime – GC Performance Improvements: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/17/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-1/